# Data is retrieving from parse database

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So I am trying to make an app where people can see which group they are in. So for every group they have made or been added to, it will be getting saved in a class on parse called "grupper". Their username are saved under column "username" and what group they are in as "gruppe".

I have been searching a while for a script which could retrieve their groups in a table view. I am not getting any errors but the table view is just blank.

I cannot point out why it does not retrieve any of the names they are in.

*I am very new to stackoverflow and swift so please let me know if i need to provide more information.*

**Here are my code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var grupper: UITableView!

var userArray: [String] = []

    func retrieveMessages() {
        let userArray: [String] = []
        let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "grupper")
        let currentUser = query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        currentUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

            for object in objects! {
                let username:String? = (object as PFObject)["gruppe"] as? String
                if username != nil {
                    self.userArray.append(username!)
                }
            }
            self.grupper.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(gruppe: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

     func grupper(grupper: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return userArray.count
    }


     func grupper(grupper: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Update - replace as with as!

        let cell = grupper.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using breakpoints to help isolate the issue? is the array not getting filled? is it not retrieving the data?

Comment: i have not tried that

Comment: I do not fully understand what this line means?        cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: Assuming `self.userArray` actually has data - try wrapping `self.grupper.reloadData()` in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { //... reload data here }`? This will reload the table view on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: instead of just copy and pasting a script of the internet, I would highly recommend you start from scratch and replicate this yourself. That way you'll understand exactly what everything does.

Comment: @originaluser2 i have tried that aswell.

Comment: @DMan It did not work. Have been trying that

Comment: did you insert your table view in you table view controller?

Comment: yes i did do insert it

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear when and from which method your `retrieveMessages` method is being called.

**First**, make sure that `retrieveMessages` is called from `viewDidLoad` (which is called the first time the view is accessed) or from `viewWillAppear` (which is called every time the view is access).

For example:

```
class YourController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        retrieveMessages()
    }

    // ... your other code is omitted for brevity ...

}
```

**Second**, if you are already doing the above (or something similar) then make sure that the query in your `retrieveMessages` method is returning data.

You could add a temporary `print` line to check the size of your`userArray` array. (Alternatively, you could use the debugger to check.)

For example:

```
func retrieveMessages() {
   // ... your code is omitted for brevity ...
   print("userArray size = \(userArray.count)")
}
```

Comment: I am still not getting anything

Comment: @PeterHughes Did you confirm that your `userArray` has data?